# Stand-alone Silverlight Web Application that need Authentication

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I am writing a stand-alone Silverlight Web Application that has the ability for users to log-in.

I also wrote a WCF server that has a service method that gets a username + password and returns true/false if the user exists in the database and the password is correct.

Because this web application is stand alone ==> I can't use the build in ASP.NET Authentication.

Is there some way to deal with this log-in in some easy way (maybe to use some exist classes)?

Is there some existing class that can enable the 'Stay signed in'?

(I'm not using RIA Services in my code)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Its not same question - i need to know how to make this without ASP.NET support because the web app. is stand alon.

Comment: Could you explain "this web application is stand alone" vs "I also wrote a WCF server"? Is the WCF service running on the client? What kind of security are you expecten then?

Comment: The stand Alon mean that i don't have any access to the web site that will be the host of the web application => that mean that all the asp.net support from the web site host does not exist. The WCF server does not run on the client machine.

Comment: @Yanshof, I don't get it. What do you mean by: "that mean that all the asp.net support from the web site host does not exist"?

Comment: i mean that i can't use the exist Authentication of the ASP.NET in my silverlight web application. Guys, i still learning the silverlight world ... maybe i made a mistake in my question ... and i dont understand something .. please fix me it is the case.

Comment: @Yanshof, the problem is not technology but the wording of your question. "Standalone" means something completely different from how you are using it. Is ASP.NET not available at all or is the Membership and Role database not available?

Comment: Yes, that it !! - the Membership and Role database not available. This is what i wanted to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to authenticate on a server that does not support ASP.NET you need another server side programming platform to create the required functionality that will run on the server. It could be any kind of Server side script, ranging from [PHP](http://www.php.net/) to [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) depending on what is available on the server.

This will probably mean that you will have to rewrite the client a bit as these platforms will use different serialization (JSON) and web service protocols (REST)

**EDIT**

Now that the question is clear (the Membership and Role database is not available) you have several options:

1. Try to get the database installed (easiest)
2. Use a file-based database (E.g., SQLServer Compact) that can be deployed along with your application (harder because you will have to setup the standard filling of the database, [but this might help](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/sql-server-compact-40-aspnet-membership.html))
3. Write a custom Membership and Role provider that authenticates against a different and [available store such as Active Directory](http://oricode.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/active-directory-role-provider/) (hardest)

Comment: Why do i need to rewrite the client side in this case ? i have already the ability to get services from my WCF server - am i wrong ?

Comment: @Yanshof, I added to my answer.

Comment: @Yanshof, The solutions I added should not require you to rewrite the client.

Comment: Thanks, i will check those options.